# Vue - InertiaJS: Enter Object not able

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

In my props, I pass the array "ticket_data" when loading the Vue component. Now I want to make a post to a controller using the Inertia form. This also works without problems.

My problem is, I can not access individual values from the array ...

My code:

```
let props = defineProps({
    ticket_data: Object,
    ticket_messages: Object,
});

let form = useForm({
    text: '',
});

let submit = () => {

    form
    .transform((data) => ({
        data,
        ticket_id: props.ticket_data.ticket_id, // null
        ticket_id: props.ticket_data, // gives all Data see Json
    }))
    .post('/account/user/support/ticket/send', {
        preserveScroll: true,
        onSuccess: () => form.reset('text'),
    });
};
```

If I submit props.ticket_data individually, the following post arrives at my controller:

```
"ticket_id":[{"user_id":1,"ticket_id":5,"reference":"Testticket","state":0,"author":"Kevin Johnson","text":"..","created_at":"11/04/22 - 19:58"}]}
```

If the data arrives with "props.ticket_data", why can't I just access it with "props.ticket_data.ticket_id" ?

"props.ticket_data.[1]" doesn't work like that either....

Comment: `props.ticket_data.[1]` is not a valid syntax. You can use something like `props.ticket_data[0]` (without the dot) if `props.ticket_data` is an array.

Comment: @Seblor Okay thanks men

Comment: @Seblor But it must be dynamically retrievable... with [0] I try to access always only statically to 0... I need however a dynamic solution

Comment: Well it depends on what you want to do. You can use forEach, a for loop, a v-for directive, etc... StackOverflow is not a coding service, we can just help you on specific problems.

Answer (score 0):

Get a ticket by Id like this:

```js
props.ticket_data.find(ticket => ticket.ticket_id === 5) // <-- ticket id
```